# Quicksight Dashboard using existing Template

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a template in Quicksight, so that it allows me to create dashboards with different datasets, but with the same structure.

I am using boto3 (Python) and the documentation indicates that a template is capable of creating a dashboard using different datasets, as long as the new dataset has the same structure as the dataset with which the template was generated.

However, when I try to create the dashboard, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateDashboard operation: Given placeholders [test_2] are not part of template
```

It would be helpful if someone could tell me the steps in the code to follow.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below image -

[image: code segment in image format]

See line 32 and description on line33.

This had me going for 2 or 3 hours, too. Same error as yourself.
From AWS CLI I derived my QS data set id. That was wrong in my case.
Use the TEMPLATE data set id instead. Issue resolved, dashboard created.

Comment: Always try to write the code segment (text format) in the answer, rather than the screenshot image of the code.